# Vuetify switch/checkbox label displaying wrong

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add a v-switch to my web app.
But it displays wrong (label should be next to v-switch, but as you can see from the picture)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: 1]

Comment: It's unclear what you trying to say ? Do you mean the alignment of label and switch ?

Comment: I mean label should be next to switch, but it isn't,

Comment: Ok got it. Let me work on it. I will share the solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this easy-CSS trick!

```
<style>
 .v-input__control label {
 top: 0px;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your source code but ideally it should work. Here is the Demo :

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      switch1: false,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-switch
        v-model="switch1"
        label="Test Switch Label"
      ></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Please let me know what challenge you are facing as per above code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the demo! The demo works perfectly, but the display bug only happens in my code...

Comment: Can you create a plunker of your code so that i can look into the issue. There might be a small CSS issue.

Comment: Yeah! Now I found a way with HTML inspector. In v-switch, there is a label component inside, and in that component, it has top:10 in style, I removed it with DevTools but any idea for removing it with pure CSS? (It's inside of v-switch), the label's class is: v-label, and it's just <label> element

Comment: Why that extra label component ? As `v-switch` already have a label attribute. You can remove that unwanted label component.

Comment: Yes, it's v-switch's label. The problem is I couldn't remove top:10 with CSS

Comment: Without plunker or jsfiddle, I will not be able to look into that. Sorry for that!

Comment: @alperen.emeksiz I found it : Please try `::v-deep .v-label { top:0 !important }`. Please make sure the `<style>` tag for this component must be scoped.

Comment: I tried yours and similars too, they didn't work sadly, but when I removed 'scope' from style and updated CSS (I posted it), it worked perfectly! Thanks for your effort BTW.